# Why Godess Parvati was not aware of Raam as Vishnu's avatar?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, parvati

In Treta yuga, when Lord Vishnu took avatar as Raam, Lord Shiva was aware about this and he took avatar as Lord Hanuman.

In the Ramayana there is a part mentioned that when Raam was in forest ( for 14 years vanvas ) with Sita & Laxmana, Godess Parvati went to forest to check actually Raam is Vishnu's avatar or not ? When Raam show her, he simply said why you are alone, where is Lord Shiva ? Hearing this she got confirmed that Raam is an avatar of Lord Vishnu.

Now when she come back to Kailash, Lord Shiva asked her about examination of Raam.

Generally when Vishnu takes any avatar, it is well known among all the devi-devtas.

So in this case Why Godess Parvati was not aware that Raam is actually an avatar of Lord Vishnu while Lord Shiva was very well known about this part ?

Comment: Where did you hear this story?

Comment: Dont you know why Lord Shiva left Godess Parvati after this incident [see this](http://www.boldsky.com/yoga-spirituality/anecdotes/2009/ramayana-short-hinduism-story-050109.html) ?

Comment: I read the link.  I've never heard of this story before.  I'm not sure what scripture, if any, it's from.  And by the way, the link doesn't mention Shiva leaving Parvati.

Comment: This story is base, the reason Lord Shiva left Parvati.

Comment: Do you have a link to the story about Shiva leaving Parvati?

Comment: Not at present.....

Comment: And do you have any idea whether this story of Parvati visiting Rama is in some scripture?

Comment: Its there in Ramayana. You may google it.

Comment: @Kesdarnath It's definitely not there in the original Ramayana.  You can read the Ramayana here: http://www.valmikiramayan.net Rama being in the forest looking for Sita is in the Aranya Kanda, and there is no mention of any visit by Siva or Parvati.  In fact the only time that Rama encounters any gods in the forest is in the hermitage of the sage Sharabanga: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga5/aranya_5_frame.htm

Comment: I think only Trimurti Shiva, Vishnu and Brahma are Trikal gyani, others are not, so they can not understand.Because these 3 only live so long and have seen all yugas, others have not.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: The incident is mentioned in Goswami Tulasidasa's Sri Ramacharitamanas (http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/ramacharitamanas/bal1-97.pdf). Pages 59-68 for the complete incident.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is Lord's *maya* which even overtakes gods and goddesses. However, it was not Parvati who got bewildered, it was Her previous incarnation Sati. The description is present in Ramacharitmanas and Shiva Purana (2.2.25).

When Sati saw that Shiva, the lord of all gods, was praising and revering Rama, a human prince, she got confused. So she asked Siva for the reason and He told that Rama is no one but Vishnu Himself. But Sati again thought, Vishnu is omniscient and the abode of all knowledge. So why He is searching and lamenting? But Shiva is omniscient also, so He also could not have told the untruth. Thus She got into doubt even after Shiva Himself told Her the truth. Seeing this, Shiva could know that the Lord's maya had got hold of Sati and He told Her to test it out Herself:

> लाग न उर उपदेसु जदपि कहेउ सिवँ बार बहु।
>   बोले बिहसि महेसु हरिमाया बलु जानि जियँ।। [RCM - 1.51]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Even if Shiva told it again and again, it made no difference to Sati. So Shiva, knowing that  She has got under the influence of Vishnu *maya*, smilingly said... (to test out Rama Herself)

So the reason is Vishnu's maya. And the thing is, even though gods and goddesses many know that Lord Hari has taken birth as a human on earth, under the influence of maya they may even fail to recognize Him. For example, in Dwapara Yuga, Brahma also got bewildered seeing Krishna eating food with cowherd boys. So He also tried to taste Lord Krishna and asked for pardon later. **Lord's *maya* is very powerful, even the gods can't escape from it**.